# ReactJS Flex Layout Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to create a login form in react.js, I searched on some tips about how to center components and results in using the following code in .css file:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

However, when I use the above code with two components(button & plaintext) inside another component(form), the app give me that both components are on the same line. I expect the plaintext goes under the button.

[Image of 2 components on the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRawZ.png)

Here's my code:

SignIn.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SignIn.css'

class SignIn extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="base-container">
                <div className="form">
                    <button className="sign-in-button" type="submit">
                        Sign In With Github
                    </button>
                    <div className="copyright">
                        Copyright © William Ji 2020
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignIn;
```

SignIn.css

```css
.base-container {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: flex;
}ß

.sign-in-button {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.copyright {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: small;
}
```

App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import SignIn from './Components/Auth/SignIn';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <SignIn />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix this just by adding to the container style **flex-wrap:wrap;** also set both of the two elements inside it (button wrap it in div + the plain text) to **width:100%**

Answer (score 0):

the copyright should be a p tag, not a div, just changing that may push it down. If not make sure it has display: block; and the container has flex-wrap: wrap;

Answer (score 0):

You need `flex-direction: column;` in the parent element. When using `display: flex;` the default is `flex-direction: row;`.

```css
#parent-with-flex-direction-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

#parent-with-flex-direction-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent-with-flex-direction-row'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='parent-with-flex-direction-column'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```